# Compiling libcurl for mingw32 (Windows) on mac os x 10.6

Tags: windows, gcc, curl, mingw

I'm compiling libcurl for mingw32 as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/daniel/mingw32 "CFLAGS= -ABI=32"
make
make install
```

But when compiling a program using mingw32-gcc:

```
i386-mingw32-gcc -lcurl -o bin/remote-win.exe remote.c
```

i get:

```
In file included from /Users/daniel/mingw32/usr/local/include/curl/curl.h:34,
                 from remote.c:6:
/Users/daniel/mingw32/usr/local/include/curl/curlbuild.h:152:26: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/daniel/mingw32/usr/local/include/curl/curl.h:34,
                 from remote.c:6:
/Users/daniel/mingw32/usr/local/include/curl/curlbuild.h:165: error: syntax error before "curl_socklen_t"
In file included from /Users/daniel/mingw32/usr/local/include/curl/curl.h:35,
                 from remote.c:6:
/Users/daniel/mingw32/usr/local/include/curl/curlrules.h:143: error: size of array `__curl_rule_01__' is negative
/Users/daniel/mingw32/usr/local/include/curl/curlrules.h:153: error: size of array `__curl_rule_02__' is negative
```

I'm pretty sure the error is because curl_socklen_t does not exist on windows. I've tried --target=*-*-mingw32 but still no success.

Please help

End of configured for:

> curl version:    7.21.4   Host setup: 
>   x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0   Install
>   prefix:  /Users/daniel/mingw32
>   Compiler:        gcc   SSL support:
>   enabled (OpenSSL)   SSH support:
>   no      (--with-libssh2)   zlib
>   support:    enabled   krb4 support:
>   no      (--with-krb4*)   GSSAPI
>   support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
>   SPNEGO support:  no
>   (--with-spnego)   TLS-SRP support: no 
>   (--enable-tls-srp)   resolver:
>   default (--enable-ares /
>   --enable-threaded-resolver)   ipv6 support:    enabled   IDN support:
>   no      (--with-libidn)   Build
>   libcurl:   Shared=yes, Static=yes
>   Built-in manual: enabled   Verbose
>   errors:  enabled (--disable-verbose)
>   SSPI support:    no
>   (--enable-sspi)   ca cert bundle:  no 
>   ca cert path:    no   LDAP support:
>   enabled (OpenLDAP)   LDAPS support:
>   enabled   RTSP support:    enabled
>   RTMP support:    no
>   (--with-librtmp)   Protocols:
>   DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS
>   IMAP IMAPS LDAP LDAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP
>   SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP

Comment: What is your configure output? Only at the end, from the line `"configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl: "`

Comment: @osgx i also get checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
the end line is above

Comment: @Daniel, your configure done for MacOS, not for mingw. "--prefix" sets only install directory, but configure knows nothing about your mingw compiler and environment. Updated the answer.

Comment: @osgx Ok thanks for the answer. i'll try it and tell you if it worked or not

Comment: Daniel, try a ' i386-pc-mingw32 ' for target and specify a CC parameter. Compiler line from configure output must begin with "Compiler: i386-mingw32-gcc "

Comment: Daniel, please, delete this loooong stuff from question, do a `make clean`, and change ' --host=mingw32' in your configure line to ' --target=i386-pc-mingw32'. Also, check how the configure works and what does it prints at the end.

Comment: ./configure --prefix=/Users/daniel/mingw32 "CFLAGS= -ABI=32" --with-gcc=i386-mingw32-gcc --with-cxx=i386-mingw32-c++ --target=i386-pc-mingw32
 comes up with: 

checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/daniel/Downloads/curl-7-1.21.4':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs. If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.

Comment: or... we must to read a `"cross-compile magic documentation ..from.. cross compile section of the docs/INSTALL file. "`. I think we must start configure with `--target=386-pc-mingw32` and `--host=x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0 `,

Comment: downloaded the without openssl build, it contains a "libcurl.dll" i copied that to mingw32/lib but same error

Comment: I'm currently trying it with --lmswsock

Comment: @osgx tried it with --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0 but getting: bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libcurl.la] Error 1

Comment: error after `-lc` is for incomplete set of mingw libraries (if it was the right compiler)

Comment: @osgx i can't find any way to install the rest of the mingw libraries??

Comment: Hmm,... my win32 mingw have no `-lc` (and don't use it `libc`). So, your linking string is still wrong. Can you find which linker is used?

Comment: @osgx how can i check what linker it used?

Comment: Find the failed compile command (post it here) and re-run it in the right directory with additional option `-v` (verbose). Then find a line with bin/ld and post it here too. Command from line with bin/ld will contain full path to linker; you also can start a linker with `-V` option to get it version.

Comment: should i compile curl with: ./configure --prefix=/Users/daniel/mingw32 "CFLAGS= -ABI=32" --target=i386-pc-mingw32 --build=x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0

Comment: maybe. Just try. Or you can read a cross-compiling documentation of curl (docs/INSTALL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like mingw have no `sys/socket.h`.  Just checked on my fresh mingw native install.

So, your application is not portable to mingw (or configure run was wrong). May be you should search or ask  in Mailing List  at http://curl.haxx.se

Thanks for your configure output.  You did configed the curl for MacOSX itself, not for a cross-build for mingw. Your should force configure to use mingw's gcc, also you should to add cross-compilation options (at least '--target' option).

Comment: Its curls source (tar.gz)
Can you please help? i don't know what to do